# After upgraded from V0.13.4 to V1.0.1, why Apache IoTDB cannot query data while can successfully run?

Tags: apache-iotdb, iotdb

I refer to the steps on the official website to upgrade the version of Apache IoTDB from V0.13.4 to V1.0.1, and change all the data directories in the settings of V1.0.1 configuration files to the data directory of V0.13.4. After this upgrade process, the IoTDB server runs successfully, but no data can be queried out. Is there any error in these step? Or is there a step I missed?

I already followed all the steps in the official guide of upgrading versions, but still got this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After updating, the data directory of Apache IoTDB V1.0.1 should not point to the original data directory of V0.13. You can set `region_group_extension_strategy`=`CUSTOM`, and for `data_region_group_per_database`, if you set distributed cluster for 3C3D, this parameter should be changed to: total number of cluster CPU cores/number of data copies. If you set the system to 1C1D, this parameter should be equal to `virtual_storage_group_num` of V0.13.